# Question about duplicate matching rule for event registrations

Tags: civievent, duplicate-contacts

what happens when you select "individualsupervised-supervised" for duplicate matching rule?  i have only selected unsupervised rule in the past, and it has caused problems because once the second child of the same parent with the same address is entered, the first child's name is on the registration again.  I want to know how to make sure if the same person registers multiple people, both or more names show up on the registration list.

Answer (score 2):

Even though many children/youth these days have their own email address - parents will often use their own for registration/event purposes - b/c they aniticipate (correctly so) that's where receipts/reminders will go.

For such registrations you need to use/create a rule like first name + email address [as last name is often also the same within a household].

I prefer Drupal - webform-civicrm for this as it allows me to set up one specific matching rule for the Primary Contact [default unsupervised] - and then I can set up different matching rules for the other (children) Contacts on the form.

See https://civicrm.org/blog/sarahgladstone/recipe-for-handling-youth-registration-with-civicrm for a nice write up/example by Sarah on how this works.